# HTML: Is it possible to import html files as templates (like calling a function)?

Tags: html, templates

(First ask here so thanks in advance for the help!)

Is there a way to import html from another file to act as templates? Similar to calling a function.

The main reason is to simplify any changes made to the website as a whole; for example changing the header navigation menu would affect the entire website's design.

Comment: Similar to the 'Global' feature on Elementor

Answer (score 1):

HTML has no features built-in to do that. The closest it gets are `<iframe>` elements which load a separate document into an embedded viewport.

This problem is generally best solved by combining your reused components before the HTML gets to the browser.

This could be done using some form of server-side programming (such as SSI, a PHP include, or a template language) or at build-time (typically using a [static site generator](https://www.google.com/search?q=static%20site%20generator%202020&rlz=1C9BKJA_enGB590GB590&oq=static%20site%20generato&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3.6014j1j7&hl=en-GB&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)).

Answer (score 0):

You can start using [Custom Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements), but there is lack of support in Opera and Safari. It looks overwhelming at first, and you need javascript experience, but it's pretty smooth once you get hang of it.

You can also use frameworks like Vue, React, Angular and Polymer that takes Custom Elements a step further.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing would be having html code surrounded with `<template>` tags and later executing Javascript code which generates final HTML document according to that template. Something like :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
.myClass {
  color: white;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
</style>

<h2>The template demo</h2>


<button onclick="showContent()">Generate document</button>

<template>
  <div class="myClass">I like: </div>
</template>

<script>
var myArr = ["Audi", "BMW", "Ford", "Honda", "Jaguar", "Nissan"];

function showContent() {
  var temp, item, a, i;
  temp = document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0];
  item = temp.content.querySelector("div");
  for (i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    a = document.importNode(item, true);
    a.textContent += myArr[i];
    document.body.appendChild(a);
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is that the solution using JS forces clients to execute arbitrary code in their browser. If what `showContent` function returns is a simple html text, then finding a way to import it statically without JS would be better.